# SQL: find missing IDs in a table

Tags: sql

I have table with a unique auto-incremental primary key. Over time, entries may be deleted from the table, so there are "holes" in this field's values. For example, table data may be as follows:

```
 ID  | Value    | More fields...
---------------------------------
 2   | Cat      | ... 
 3   | Fish     | ...
 6   | Dog      | ...
 7   | Aardvark | ...
 9   | Owl      | ...
 10  | Pig      | ...
 11  | Badger   | ...
 15  | Mongoose | ...
 19  | Ferret   | ...
```

I'm interested in a query that will return the list of missing IDs in the table. For the data above, the expected results are:

```
 ID 
----
 1
 4
 5
 8
 12
 13
 14
 16
 17
 18
```

Notes:

1. It is assumed that the initial first ID was 1
2. The maximum ID that should be examined is the final one, i.e. it's okay to assume that there were no additional entries after the current last one (see additional data on this point below)

A drawback of the above requirements is that the list will not return IDs that were created after ID 19 and that were deleted. I'm currently solving this case in code, because I hold the max ID created. However, if the query can take as a parameter MaxID, and also return those IDs between the current max and MaxID, that would be a nice "bonus" (but certainly not a must).

I'm currently working with MySQL, but consider moving to SQL Server, so I would like the query to fit both. Also, if you are using anything that can't run on SQLite, please mention it, thanks.

Comment: Look for the first answer in
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141129/find-ids-from-a-list-that-dont-exist-in-a-table by a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This question often comes up, and sadly, the most common (and most portable) answer is to create a temporary table to hold the IDs that *should* be there, and do a left join. The syntax is pretty similar between MySQL and SQL Server. The only real difference is the temporary tables syntax.

In MySQL:

```
declare @id int
declare @maxid int

set @id = 1
select @maxid = max(id) from tbl

create temporary table IDSeq
(
    id int
)

while @id < @maxid
begin
    insert into IDSeq values(@id)

    set @id = @id + 1
end

select 
    s.id 
from 
    idseq s 
    left join tbl t on 
        s.id = t.id 
 where t.id is null

 drop table IDSeq
```

In SQL Server:

```
declare @id int
declare @maxid int

set @id = 1
select @maxid = max(id) from tbl

create table #IDSeq
(
    id int
)

while @id < @maxid --whatever you max is
begin
    insert into #IDSeq values(@id)

    set @id = @id + 1
end

select 
    s.id 
from 
    #idseq s 
    left join tbl t on 
        s.id = t.id 
 where t.id is null

 drop table #IDSeq
```

Comment: Im not sure what the scenario is in this environment, but what if it were not 20, but say a thousand records? ..and this were called by code on a web page serving 50-60 users concurrently. would it be efficient to create and drop those records everytime? Considering we leave out the part where we create and drop the temp table.

Comment: @daemonkid: Man, what a freaking strawman. If you had to figure this out time and time again, for 50-60 users, you'd obviously want a permanent table. You obviously have to adapt to your specific scenario, but this is a solution to the problem of finding the missing IDs.

Comment: I couldn't get the MySql query to work (syntax errors). So I think I'll just export IDs to Excel and do some comparisons there (to a list of sequential numbers).

Comment: Although it works with the example data it is not good for large amount of records. The "while" alone will take several seconds to finish if want a range bigger than 100.000

Comment: @GustavoCardoso It works great for 100,000+ rows. Completes in about 5 seconds. Why is 5 seconds a problem? You would never need to run code like this more than once (if you did, then you're application design is totally wrong).

Answer (score 55):

I landed on this page hoping to find a solution for SQLITE as this was the only answer I found when searching for this same question for SQLITE.

The final solution I found was from this article here
[Float Middle Blog - SQLITE answer](http://float-middle.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/find-missing-value-in-sequence-in.html)

Hope it helps someone else out :-)

the simple solution being:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id +1
FROM mytable
WHERE id + 1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM mytable);
```

genius.

Comment: May I suggest (more than one year later) a small improvement which eliminates in SQLITE the biggest missing value returned which is always max(id) + 1 : just add at the end of the query : AND id < (SELECT max(id) FROM mytable); [Hope it helps someone just like you helped me]

Comment: This only partly works. If you have ID 24, but not 25 or 26, this request will get ID 25, but not ID 26, so you will forget to fix the situation for ID 26.

Comment: Be aware, you will be missing values if you use this solution.  I tested it but like @conradkleinespel mentions, if you have more than one missing identity value in a row, it will only capture the first one.

Comment: This is pretty cool if you know the limitation you can write some logic to recheck after whatever op you need. In my case I am fetching data and filling in the blanks so I just keep running this until returns nothing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55094002/3121607

Answer (score 25):

Here's the query for SQL Server:

```
;WITH Missing (missnum, maxid)
AS
(
 SELECT 1 AS missnum, (select max(id) from @TT)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT missnum + 1, maxid FROM Missing
 WHERE missnum < maxid
)
SELECT missnum
FROM Missing
LEFT OUTER JOIN @TT tt on tt.id = Missing.missnum
WHERE tt.id is NULL
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I get: Error: Must declare the table variable "@TT".

Answer (score 23):

PostgreSQL-only, inspired by other answers here.

```
SELECT all_ids AS missing_ids
FROM generate_series((SELECT MIN(id) FROM your_table), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM your_table)) all_ids
EXCEPT 
SELECT id FROM your_table
```

Comment: I find this one very useful for postgres. The link to generate_series function is as follows: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-srf.html.  I am glad I found this solution.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, the IDs came out in a very random looking order, so I added `ORDER BY missing_ids` at the end.

Answer (score 9):

I know it's an old question and already has an accepted answer, 
but using a temp table isn't really necessary. Fixed formatting (sorry for double post).

```
DECLARE @TEST_ID integer, @LAST_ID integer, @ID integer

SET @TEST_ID = 1 -- start compare with this ID 
SET @LAST_ID = 100 -- end compare with this ID

WHILE @TEST_ID <= @LAST_ID 
BEGIN 
  SELECT @ID = (SELECT <column> FROM <table> WHERE <column> = @TEST_ID) 
  IF @ID IS NULL 
  BEGIN 
    PRINT 'Missing ID: ' + CAST(@TEST_ID AS VARCHAR(10)) 
  END 
  SET @TEST_ID = @TEST_ID + 1 
END
```

Comment: This works, but it appears to make a connection for each result. If the LAST_ID were a large number it appears that it could make thousands of connections.

Answer (score 5):

This is an Oracle only solution.  It doesn't address the full question, but is left here for others that may be using Oracle.

```
select level id           -- generate 1 .. 19
from dual
connect by level <= 19

minus                     -- remove from that set

select id                 -- everything that is currently in the 
from table                -- actual table
```

Answer (score 3):

> to get the missing rows from table

```
DECLARE @MaxID INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE1)
SELECT SeqID AS MissingSeqID
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_id) SeqID from sys.columns) LkUp
LEFT JOIN dbo.TABLE1 t ON t.ID = LkUp.SeqID
WHERE t.ID is null and SeqID < @MaxID
```

Answer (score 3):

I just have found the solution for Postgres:

```sql
select min(gs) 
from generate_series(1, 1999) as gs 
where gs not in (select id from mytable)
```

Comment: Slight improvement to get all ids that are missing: `select gs 
from generate_series(1, (select MAX(id) from mytable)) as gs 
where gs not in (select id from mytable)`

Answer (score 0):

The single query can find the missing IDs..

```
SELECT distinct number

FROM master..spt_values

WHERE number BETWEEN 1 and (SELECT max(id) FROM MyTable)

AND number NOT IN (SELECT id FROM MyTable)
```

Comment: Note: This answer is specific to SQL Server

Comment: Strange.. not working on MS SQL Server 2008. Table contains 600k records, this query checks only 2150.

Comment: @naXa that's because `spt_values` is just a table with a bunch of random numbers. This answer is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This method took way too long so I wrote a linux command to find gaps in a text file. It does so in reverse order so first dump all id's to a text file like so;

```
nohup mysql --password=xx -e 'select id from tablename order by id desc' databasename > /home/ids.txt &
```

The first and last two lines are just to keep track of how long it took. 1.5million IDs(ish) took me 57sec & that's on a slow server. Set the max id in i and have at it.

```
T="$(date +%s)"; \
i=1574115; \
while read line; do \
    if  [[ "$line" != "$i" ]] ; then \
        if [[ $i -lt 1 ]] ; then break; fi; \
        if  [[ $line -gt 1 ]] ; then \
            missingsequenceend=$(( $line + 1 )); \
            minusstr="-"; \
            missingsequence="$missingsequenceend$minusstr$i"; \
            expectnext=$(( $line - 1 )); \
            i=$expectnext; \
            echo -e "$missingsequence"; \
        fi; \
    else \
        i=$(( $i - 1 )); \
    fi; \
done \
< /home/ids.txt; \
T="$(($(date +%s)-T))"; \
echo "Time in seconds: ${T}"
```

Example output:

```
1494505-1494507
47566-47572
Time in seconds: 57
```

Also, I got syntax errors with the code from Eric's answer, but after changing the delimiter, using semicolons in the proper places and storing it in a procedure, it works.

Make sure you set the proper max ID, database name and table name (it's in the select query). And if you want to change the procedure name, change it in all 3 places.

```
use dbname;
drop procedure if exists dorepeat;
delimiter #
CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat()
BEGIN
set @id = 1;
set @maxid = 1573736;
drop table if exists IDSeq;
create temporary table IDSeq
(
    id int
);

WHILE @id < @maxid DO
    insert into IDSeq values(@id);
    set @id = @id + 1;
END WHILE;

select 
    s.id 
from 
    IDSeq s 
    left join tablename t on 
        s.id = t.id 
 where t.id is null;

drop table if exists IDSeq;

END#
delimiter ;
CALL dorepeat;
```

I also found this query elwhere, but I haven't tested it.

```
SELECT a.id+1 AS start, MIN(b.id) - 1 AS end
    FROM tablename AS a, tablename AS b
    WHERE a.id < b.id
    GROUP BY a.id
    HAVING start < MIN(b.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY in **MySQL**

```
DELIMITER ||
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_missing ||
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_missing()
BEGIN 
SET @minID = (SELECT MIN(`id`) FROM `tbl_name` WHERE `user_id`=13);
SET @maxID = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `tbl_name` WHERE `user_id`=13);
REPEAT 
    SET @tableID = (SELECT `id` FROM `tbl_name` WHERE `id` = @minID);
    IF (@tableID IS NULL) THEN
        INSERT INTO temp_missing SET `missing_id` = @tableID;
    END IF;
    SET @minID = @minID + 1;
UNTIL(@minID <= @maxID)
END REPEAT;
END ||
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago, I was working on a production report and found some numbers missing. The missing numbers are very important, so I was asked to find a list of all missing numbers for investigation purposes. [I posted a blog entry here, with a full demo, including a script to find missing numbers/IDs in a sample table.](http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/06/query-to-find-missing-number-id-sql-server/)

The script suggested is quite long, so I won't include it here. Here are the basic steps used:

1. Create one temp table and store all distinct Numbers.
2. Find NextID which has something missing before it. Store into one TempTable.
3. Create one temp table to store missing number details.
4. Start to find the missing id using WHILE Loop.
5. Select missing data from #MissingID temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the SQL CTE (from Paul Svirin) to the Oracle version it looks like this (replace :YOURTABLE with the name of your table):

```
WITH Missing (missnum,maxid) as (
  SELECT 1 missnum, (select max(id) from :YOURTABLE) maxid from dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT m.missnum + 1,m.maxid 
  FROM Missing m
  WHERE m.missnum < m.maxid
)
SELECT missnum
FROM Missing
LEFT OUTER JOIN :YOURTABLE tt on tt.id = Missing.missnum
WHERE tt.id is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `@PaulSvirin`'s answer, I've expanded it with a `UNION` to show ALL the data in my table, including the missing records with `NULL`s.

```
WITH Missing(missnum, maxid) AS
          (SELECT (SELECT MIN(tmMIN.TETmeetingID)
                   FROM tblTETMeeting AS tmMIN)
                      AS missnum,
                  (SELECT MAX(tmMAX.TETmeetingID)
                   FROM tblTETMeeting AS tmMAX)
                      AS maxid
           UNION ALL
           SELECT missnum + 1, maxid
           FROM Missing
           WHERE missnum < maxid)
SELECT missnum AS TETmeetingID,
       tt.DateID,
       tt.WeekNo,
       tt.TETID
FROM Missing LEFT JOIN tblTETMeeting tt ON tt.TETmeetingID = Missing.missnum
WHERE tt.TETmeetingID IS NULL
UNION
SELECT tt.TETmeetingID,
       tt.DateID,
       tt.WeekNo,
       tt.TETID
FROM tblTETMeeting AS tt
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 )
```

Work's great!

```
TETmeetingID    DateID  WeekNo  TETID
29  3063    21  1
30  null    null    null
31  null    null    null
32  null    null    null
33  null    null    null
34  3070    22  1
35  3073    23  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution for me: Create a select that gives all ids up to max sequence value (ex:1000000), and filter:

```
with listids as (
Select Rownum idnumber From dual Connect By Rownum <= 1000000)

select * from listids
where idnumber not in (select id from table where id <=1000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

A modified version borrowing @Eric proposal. This is for SQL Server and holds in a temp table the start and end value for missing ranges. If the gap is just one value it puts `NULL` as end value for easier visualization.

It will produce an output like this

```
|StartId| EndId |
|-------|-------|
|     1 | 10182 |
| 10189 | NULL  |
| 10246 | 15000 |
```

And this is the script where `myTable` and `id` needs to be replaced by your table and identity column.

```
declare @id bigint
declare @endId bigint
declare @maxid bigint
declare @previousid bigint=0

set @id = 1
select @maxid = max(id) from myTable

create table #IDGaps
(
    startId bigint,
    endId bigint
)

while @id < @maxid
begin
    if NOT EXISTS(select id from myTable where id=@id)
    BEGIN
        SET @previousid=@id
        select top 1 @endId=id from myTable where id>@id

        IF @id=@endId-1
            insert into #IDGaps values(@id,null)
        ELSE
            insert into #IDGaps values(@id,@endId-1)

        SET @id=@endId
        
    END
    ELSE
        set @id = @id + 1
end

select * from #IDGaps

drop table #IDGaps
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION FOR SQLITE

if your table id only support positive values you can use this

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT table_id - 1 AS next_id
FROM table
WHERE next_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT table_id FROM table)
  AND next_id > 0
```

otherwise you should remove ids greater than the biggest id with

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT table_id + 1 AS next_id
FROM table
WHERE next_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT table_id FROM table)
  AND id < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked in SQLITE:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE series(x) AS (
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM series
  LIMIT (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table))
SELECT x FROM series WHERE x NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table)
```

It creates a recursive Common Table Expression which starts with 1 (`SELECT 1`) and for each value in the generated table creates a value which is one bigger (`SELECT x+1 FROM series`). Then it merges with existing values (`UNION ALL`). The `LIMIT` sets the upper bound of the generated values.

The second command creates diff between generated range of numbers and `id`s existing in the `table`.

Answer (score -1):

This problem can be solved with only one query

```
select lft.id + 1 as missing_ids
from tbl as lft left outer join tbl as rght on lft.id + 1 = rght.id
where rght.id is null and lft.id between 1 and (Select max(id)-1 from tbl)
```

Tested on Mysql

Comment: This only finds missing IDs that are 1 greater than existing IDs.  In the OPs case it misses most of the missing IDs.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45412/1

Answer (score -1):

**Try This Query. This single query is enough to get missing numbers:(Please replace TABLE_NAME to which table name you are using)**

```
select sno as missing from(SELECT @row := @row + 1 as sno FROM 
(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all 
select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all 
select 8 union all select 9) t,(select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 
union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 
union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2,(select 0 
union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 
union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 
union all select 9) t3, (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union 
all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all 
select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t4, 
(SELECT @row:=0) as b where @row<1000) as a where a.sno  not in 
  (select distinct b.no from 
(select b.*,if(@mn=0,@mn:=b.no,@mn) as min,(@mx:=b.no) as max from 
  (select ID as no from TABLE_NAME as a) as b,
        (select @mn:=0,@mx:=0) as x order by no) as b) and 
         a.sno between @mn and @mx;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id -1
FROM users
WHERE id != 1 AND id - 1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM users)
```

**Explanation:**  ( id - 1 )..... checking for any previous id present in table

( id != 1 ).....neglecting when current id is 1 as its previous id will be 0 zero.

Comment: nice try but miss some missing ids

Answer (score -1):

I have a large audit table and needed something that ran quickly - this worked well for me. It merges the top and bottom IDs for the missing ranges

```
select minQ.num,minId,maxId from 

(SELECT DISTINCT id +1 as minId, Row_Number() Over ( Order By id ) As Num
FROM tblAuditLoghistory
WHERE id + 1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tblAuditLogHistory)
AND id < (SELECT max(id) FROM tblAuditLoghistory)) Minq
 join


(SELECT DISTINCT id - 1 as maxId, Row_Number() Over ( Order By id ) As Num
FROM tblAuditLoghistory
WHERE id - 1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tblAuditLogHistory)
AND id > (SELECT min(id) FROM tblAuditLoghistory)) maxQ on minQ.num=maxQ.num
```

Answer (score -2):

This what i used to find the missing id of one table named as tablename

`select a.id+1 missing_ID from tablename a
where a.id+1 not in (select id from tablename b where b.id=a.id+1)
and a.id!=(select id from tablename c order by id desc limit 1)`

It will return the missing ids.
If there are two(2) or more continuous missing ids, it will return only the first.