# Mysql, finding missing numbers in a sequence

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have a huge table with a couple hundred thousand records.  They all have a unique id for the first column though some are missing in the sequence of numbers.

I am trying to show a list of the numbers that are missing individually.

So for example:

```
10029
10032
10034
10036
```

I am trying to get it to show:

```
10030
10031
10033
10035
```

I found this query but it seems to be missing numbers when there's a range:

```
SELECT t1.id+1 AS Missing 
FROM data AS t1 
LEFT JOIN data AS t2 
    ON t1.id+1 = t2.id 
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Result:

```
10030
10033
```

As you can see, 10031 and 10035 are missing from that list.

Comment: This question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389605/sql-find-missing-ids-in-a-table

Comment: If you can create a temporary table containing all the IDs from `min(id)` to `max(id)`, you can do a left join between them.

Comment: Is there a way I can do this within the query without creating another table?  I am trying to do this as simple as possible so I can use it within a PHP query.

I saw another example that used:
SELECT a.order_id+1 AS start, MIN(b.order_id) - 1 AS end

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this as a starting point. Not tested, but might just work

```
SELECT @min := (SELECT min(id) FROM yourtable); // get the smallest ID in the table
SELECT @last := @min; // cache the min value for the where clause

SELECT id, id - @last AS difference, @last := id
FROM yourtable
WHERE id > @min
ORDER BY id ASC
HAVING difference > 1
```

it won't give you the individual missing ids, but it'll tell you where the gaps are, and how big they are.