# How to get not exist records from table SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry if my question was stupid or basic.I trying to get not exist id records from db. But it is showing all records.

```
---------------------+
id  |  name  |  age  |
---------------------+
 1  |   ase  |   33  |
 3  |   ase  |   33  |
 4  |   ase  |   33  |
 5  |   ase  |   33  |
 7  |   ase  |   33  |
 9  |   ase  |   33  |
---------------------+
```

i tried something like this

SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id NO IN ('1','2','4','5','6','7') but it showing all records. In this given query id 2,6 are not exist in table show i need to show them as result. please some one help me to solve this. thanks

expecting output like

```
----------------------+
id not exist in table |
----------------------+
          2           |
          6           |
----------------------+
```

from the given IN statement this ID are not exist in TABLE something like this. I need to show id which are not exist in table as result.

Comment: You need a Numbers table for this.

Comment: i have updated question. 
from the given ID which are not exist in TABLE should show as output

Comment: Well you an use [similar query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389605/sql-find-missing-ids-in-a-table) for finding missing IDs.

Comment: Thank you  Muhammad Abid :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a (derived) table of values.  Here is a solution using `left join` instead of `not in`:

```
select n.n
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
      select 6 union all select 7
     ) n left join
     tablename t
     on t.id = n.n
where t.id is null;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But i am having more 300 IDs , is there any query something like IN ( 1,2,3...etcc.)

Comment: You should put the values into a table and use the table in the query.