# how to automatically set new id value as id of already deleted row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 50 rows, `id` column as primary key, autoincrement.

At the beginning `id` values where from 1 - 50;

After deleting a row, for example `id=1`, and inserting a new row, this will have `id=51`.

How can I set the new row to take first empty place, it this case `id=1` automatically, instead of `51`;

Also if `id=5` is deleted, the next inserted row should have `id=5` an so on.

Comment: This is useless.

Comment: @u_mulder, this is usefull for me

Comment: don't delete the row in DB just update that with new user value

Comment: I doubt that. You will spend time in vain.

Comment: Don't really see the point of this either, but you could `SELECT` the first empty id before doing your `INSERT` query.

Comment: @roberto06, how can I select first empty id ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: find missing IDs in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389605/sql-find-missing-ids-in-a-table)

Comment: write a `trigger` for specfic table  to store the deleted id in `temptable` while `insert` check any id is exists in `temptable` if so use the id and delete tat id from the temptable or else leave it `null` `auto increment` will do the rest

Comment: If that deleted `ID` will be linked with some other table. Then, you will get unwanted results. @Bonaca I recommend you not to use.

Comment: What's the benefit of reusing the IDs?

Comment: But I'm very doubtful on the reason why you NEED this...?

Comment: @axiac, the benefit is in automatically creating a short password for each row, which is `id` value multiplied with 9, for example. If `id` is long, the password is too long.

Comment: There is no benefit. You're using the `auto_increment` field wrong. The "gaps" occur for a reason. When you try to "fill" the gaps, you open a pandora's box. But hey, why should you listen to some programmers on internet telling you this is bad, they probably have no clue, right? What's funny is that you're the one asking the question.. but you know better.

Comment: @Mjh, my question is not is it bad or not. The question is how to do something.

Comment: Reading your comment on why you need this - it's absolutely useless. Questions such as yours give other visitors bad ideas. It matters whether what you want to do is bad or not because we need to *responsibly* handle knowledge. You're using the `auto_increment` field for something that's not it's purpose. You have some sort of logic with passwords that depends on value of `auto_increment` field. You've done two very stupid, very dangerous things - and you don't heed the warning, which is fine. I'm not answering, I'm commenting, hoping it will warn others not to walk across the burning bridge.

Comment: If password is the only reason to reuse the IDs then I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem. I can imagine a handful of other ways to generate a short password. I hope it is a temporary password.

Comment: Reusing the IDs is wrong at its heart. An ID must **uniquely identify** an object. Is the new object the same thing as the deleted object? I guess not. They are different entities, apart from the reused ID, they have different identities, they cannot be replaced one for another. Reusing the IDs has undesired effects in the future, in ways you cannot predict now.

Comment: @axiac, no, the new object cannot be the same as deleted object, because deleted object IS DELETED, it doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not talking about the data you store in the database. I'm talking about the object it represents in your system. The deleted object played a role in your system. It was probably linked to other entities, it possibly left traces in log files, appeared in generated URLs, object collections etc. It was identified by its unique ID in all these places (or otherwise the ID column is useless in the table). If you now assign the old ID to a different object, many things could go wrong. It's identity theft, you know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's query variables to track the previous id and calculate the difference in the query, e,g.:

```
SELECT id, id - @previous AS difference, @previous := id
FROM test, (SELECT @previous := 0) a
ORDER BY id;
```

This would give you all the ids with difference. You can then wrap this into another query and `SELECT` the rows with difference > 1 to get the available id, e.g.:

```
SELECT (id - difference + 1) AS available_id
FROM (
 SELECT id, id - @previous AS difference, @previous := id
 FROM test, (SELECT @previous := 0) a
 ORDER BY id) b
WHERE b.difference > 1
LIMIT 1;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9712b4/7/0)**.

Answer (score 2):

With autoincrement columns you can not change the keys checks per row.
You could disable key checks and the truncate the table which will reassign new keys(numbers) to each row, but that means previous keys will move to other rows depending on how many deleted rows and where they were in the sequence.

If you really need to do something like what you are doing, you could alternatively create a faux-indexed "auto" incremented column by your script. Then you would be able to manage that column in any manner that you chose to.