# Find missing numbers in a sequence in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say i have a table with an integer column Id. I need to find the `missing numbers` in a `sequence` with a maximum returned amount.

- If the table is empty and i'm asking for 10, it should return the numbers 1-10.
- If the table has 1-5 and i'm asking for 10, it should return the numbers 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15.
- If the table has 1,2,4,6,9 and im asking for 10, it should return the numbers 3,5,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15

How can i achive this in one single query using `MS SQL`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: find missing IDs in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389605/sql-find-missing-ids-in-a-table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

If you need to get more numbers, just increase the `WHERE Number<=100`.

```
DECLARE @Tab1 TABLE (ID INT)

INSERT INTO @Tab1 VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO @Tab1 VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO @Tab1 VALUES(5)
INSERT INTO @Tab1 VALUES(7)
INSERT INTO @Tab1 VALUES(9)

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1 FROM CTE
    WHERE Number<=100
)
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM CTE
WHERE Number NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM @Tab1)
ORDER BY Number
OPTION (maxrecursion 0);
```

**Existing values:**

```
Number
1
3
5
7
9
```

**OutPut:**

```
Number
2
4
6
8
10
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Looks promising.. 

What does this do:
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1 FROM CTE
    WHERE Number<=100
)

Comment: @LasseO, This is for generating numbers in sequence. Using that sequence we eliminate the existing numbers from the table.

Comment: This is OK, but keep in mind 2 things. If you request many rows, you might need to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION X)` at the end, and I would suggest changing the `NOT IN` for a `NOT EXISTS` if your table is big or it has `NULL` IDs.

Comment: I'm using this to get which file chunk id's has not yet been uploaded. There can be thousands of chunks though. I believe this only supports op to 100?

Comment: @LasseO, That's what I clearly said you in the answer. If you need more numbers, you increase the value in the `where` condition inside the `CTE`.

Comment: Yeah, but i get this error:

"The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci, how would that look?

Comment: @LasseO Try my Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work
There are also a system table with numbers

```
declare @T table (i int primary key);
insert into @T values (1), (2), (4), (6), (9); 
declare @count int = 10;
declare @size int = (select count(*) from @T);
with cte as
( select 1 as num
  union all 
  select num + 1 
  from cte
  where num + 1 <= (@count + @size)
)
select top (@count) cte.num 
from cte 
left join @T t 
  on t.i = cte.num 
where t.i is null 
order by cte.num 
option ( MaxRecursion 0 );
```