# SQL Server : efficient way to find missing Ids

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server to store tens of millions of records. I need to be able to query its tables to find missing rows where there are gaps in the Id column, as there should be none.

I am currently using a solution that I have found here on StackOverflow:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[find_missing_ids]
    @Table NVARCHAR(128)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @query = 'WITH Missing (missnum, maxid) '
+ N'AS '
+ N'('
+ N' SELECT 1 AS missnum, (select max(Id) from ' + @Table + ') '
+ N'    UNION ALL '
+ N'    SELECT missnum + 1, maxid FROM Missing '
+ N'    WHERE missnum < maxid '
+ N') '
+ N'SELECT missnum '
+ N'FROM Missing '
+ N'LEFT OUTER JOIN ' + @Table + ' tt on tt.Id = Missing.missnum '
+ N'WHERE tt.Id is NULL '
+ N'OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);';

    EXEC sp_executesql @query
END;
```

This solution has been working very well, but it has been getting slower and more resource intensive as the tables have grown. Now, running the procedure on a table of 38 million rows is taking about 3.5 minutes and lots of CPU.

Is there a more efficient way to perform this? After a certain range has been found to not contain any missing Ids, I no longer need to check that range again.

Comment: I would generate  tally table using different method than recursive cte like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394239/5070879. Second thing ID could have gaps both for IDENTITY/SEQUENCE

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312101/how-do-i-find-a-gap-in-running-counter-with-sql) for finding a gap in a running counter.

Comment: I suggest making use of `QUOTENAME`, what you have there is very open to injection

Comment: The real question is why do you care about gaps in the id columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JBJ's answer is almost complete.  The query needs to return the From and Through for each range of missing values.

```
select B+1 as [From],A-1 as[Through]from
(select StuffID as A, 
lag(StuffID)over(order by StuffID)as B from Stuff)z
where A<>B+1
order by A
```

I created a test table with 50 million records, then deleted a few.  The first row of the result is:

```
From   Through
33     35
```

This indicates that all IDs in the range from 33 through 35 are missing, i.e. 33, 34 and 35.

On my machine the query took 37 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select pId 
from (select Id, lag(Id) over (order by Id) pId from yourschema.yourtable) e
where pId <> (Id-1)
order by Id
```

replacing yourschema.yourtable with the appropriate table information

Comment: How will that work for gaps of more than a single value, e.g. `1, 2, 5, 13`?

Comment: next option is to loop through each id and if not found put it in a table but adding the new records in with the new id's would require set identity_insert off/on, not the best way. there are 2 possible datatypes you could use for a new Id column, bigint starting low (identity(-9223372036854775808,1) not null primary key) or a uniqueidentifier default(newid()) not null primary key. Both would require dropping the PK index before adding to the table and would both wreak havoc to all tables relying on the old key.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, it will be faster than `CTE`.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER ( 
           ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN 
FROM   ( values  (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) v(id) --10 ROWS 
       CROSS JOIN ( values  (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) v1(id)--100 ROWS 
       CROSS JOIN ( values  (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) v2(id) --1000 ROWS 
       CROSS JOIN ( values  (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) v3(id) --10000 ROWS 
       CROSS JOIN ( values  (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) v4(id)--100000 ROWS 
       CROSS JOIN ( values  (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) v5(id)--1000000 ROWS 
)

SELECT RN AS Missing 
FROM CTE C
LEFT JOIN YOURABLE T ON T.ID=R.ID
WHERE T.ID IS NULL
```

If you want you can use `master..[spt_values]` also to generate the number like following.

```
 SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) RN 
        FROM   master..[spt_values] T1
        CROSS JOIN (select top 500 * from master..[spt_values]) T2
```

Above query will generate `1268500` numbers

Note: You need to add the `CROSS JOIN` as per your requirement.