# Find Missing Identity Values In Auto Increment Column

Tags: sql-server

I have table with identity column `seqno`. I want to find missing no in this column.

Note :
I have only read permission in this table only.

My code:

```
SELECT Rno 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         seqno, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY seqno) AS Rno 
     FROM trnmast) a 
WHERE 
    seqno <> rno
```

I run this but not getting correct result.

Example :

| SeqNo |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 10 |

I want only missing no like this :

| seqNo |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 9 |

I have only read permission of this table only.

Comment: Dare I ask: what's the motivation / need to find those "missing" sequence numbers? What if you've found all those "missing" sequence numbers - then what?

Comment: I want to find list of missing number in my auto increment column. because of I have another table that is dependent on this column so, I need to find missing number and getting right data from back up table.

Comment: I can't access of back table direct so, I need missing no.

Comment: `select top((select max(seqno) from trnmast)) row_number() over(order by @@spid) as seqno
from sys.all_columns as a
cross join sys.all_columns as b
except
select seqno from trnmast`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL: find missing IDs in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389605/sql-find-missing-ids-in-a-table)

Comment: @lptr thanks your replay , your query is right it's give perfect answered. But problem is there I have no access other future of database. only read permission in this table can you help without using `sys.all_columns`.

Comment: Does getting a list of numbers in your other table that do not exist in the trnmast table solve your issue?

Comment: @MeyssamToluie is it not. I have do this with permission.

Comment: @Joe I have write down in my question I have limited access of database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an option where you **DON'T** need to create a tally table.  It uses an ad-hoc tally table.

**Example**

```
Select N 
 From ( Select Top (Select max(SeqNo) From TRNMAST) 
               N= Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
         From  TRNMAST n1, TRNMAST n2  ) N
 Left Join TRNMAST
  on  SeqNo=N 
 Where SeqNo is Null
```

**Results**

```
N
2
5
6
9
```

Results

Comment: thanks for replay but I have no access of master database. limited permission only.

Comment: @PiyushKachhadiya  FYI ... any table of adequate size will do.   You could even use TRNMAST

Comment: john-cappelletti it's fastest way to do this thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a lookup table (a table variable) contains the seqno from 1 to the maximum number in your table.

**Query**

```
declare @t as table(seqno int);
declare @n as int, @s as int;
set @s = 1;
select @n = max(seqno) from yourTable;
while(@s <= @n)
begin
  insert into @t
  select @s;
  set @s += 1;
end

select * from @t
where seqno not in (select seqno from yourTable);
```

Comment: thanks for replay, I was run this with change of `int` to `bigint` datatype, it's tack to much time. can you suggest for more faster way.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to have a "tally" (numbers) table (that contains a column `Number` with the numbers, from 1 through (n) - however high you want to go) and then do something like this:

```
SELECT
    number
FROM
    dbo.TallyTable tt
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.trnmast trn ON tt.Number = trn.seqno
WHERE
    trn.seqno IS NULL
```

Take the tally table, left join to your `trnmast` table on the `seqno` and get those entries from the tally table that aren't present in the `trnmast` table.

Of course - you must first *have* (or *create*) such a tally table - there are lots of blog posts and articles on how to do that - just do some research and you'll find ways to do this easily!

Comment: @marc-s thanks for replay, but I can't do this because of I have no permission in database to create table, I have only read permission of this table so it's not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @minimum INT
SELECT @minimum = MIN(seqno) FROM #temp

;WITH Missing (missnum, maxid)
AS
(
 SELECT @minimum AS missnum, (select max(seqno) from #temp)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT missnum + 1, maxid FROM Missing
 WHERE missnum < maxid
)
SELECT missnum
FROM Missing
LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp tt on tt.seqno = Missing.missnum
WHERE tt.seqno is NULL
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

`Result` : [enter link description here](https://dbfiddle.uk/dl8Aj4bY)

Comment: Curious.  This would ONLY identify the NEXT missing 1 ( including the top limit +1).   Also,  NOT IN ( ... ) could get rather expensive if there is a deep population.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I was run this it's give me perfect answer and fastest result all of this. in my table billion of records.

Comment: If you are comfortable, that's fine.  Going by the sample data, It won't return 6 and returns 11 as well.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti now, I added with link please suggest best one.

Comment: Having a billion rows, I hate both.   Recursive CTEs re good for small data, and the LOOP is the wost thing imaginable.

Comment: Just saying on my laptop I tried my approach on 256MM rows and got 190K missing records in less than 2 seconds.   Loops are expensive and I can't imagine them outperforming a set based approach.