# How to get block of unused ids in table with LTS?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have dropped on this question: [SQL query to find Missing sequence numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057389).  I want to achieve the same thing but with LINQ to SQL.

**To recap:** I have a table with ids like 1,2,4,5,10,11,12,15, [...].
I want the unused ids 3,6,7,8,9,13,14, [...].

Can we create a temporary sequence and use the same logic as in T-SQL?

I tried to create a temp array of integers as a temp sequence, it works, but since the ids in the table is going up to 900,000 and more, I don't think it's the optimal way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your table of integer values "strs" this should retrieve the missing integer values:

```
var missing = from i in Enumerable.Range(strs.Min(),strs.Max())
              where !strs.Contains(i)
              select i;
```

Comment: Wow! One year later! :P  A little thing if I may note: the Enumerable.Range has parameters (start, count), so in the first place, by reading the code I thought the result Ids where between the first and the last integers in strs...  But it's working great, thank you!

Comment: Ha! Didn't notice the post date. Yes, my mistake (incorrect assumption) re the arguments to Enumerable.Range. I guess Enumerable.Range(strs.Min(), strs.Max()-strs.Min()) will do the trick.