# SQL Server 2008 finding missing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, gaps-and-islands, missing-data

I have a huge DB and one table in particular is missing rows. I know this to be true but I need to find the gaps and show them. The primary key is the sequence number column. I need to show the actual missing sequence numbers. This table has 76,054,525 rows of data.

Update, the sequence number is provided by our software and each one represents a unique "play" record. Our software does not allow for gaps in play sequence numbers. Any gaps would be missing data.

Comment: Do a self join and find the `NULL`?

Comment: Here's a similar question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057389/sql-query-to-find-missing-sequence-numbers

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson you removed the *hugs*...

Comment: @bluefeet Someone hates hugs.

Comment: Why do you need to show the missing sequence numbers? Why do you care?

Answer (score 3):

That is a gaps and islands problem and a lot of people have written about how to solve that. For example, Itzik Ben-Gan covered it in [chapter 5](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf) of the SQL Server MVP Deep Dives book

However, why are you worried about gaps in your identity column? That is something that naturally occurs and cant be prevented. You can read more about that here: http://sqlity.net/en/792/the-gap-in-the-identity-value-sequence/

Comment: @billinkc, just was making the edit to add Itziks book (chapter) myself. Thank you though for improving my answer.

Comment: You stole my answer so it was the least I could do ;)