# Show records which dont match the date year sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

how records which dont match the date year sequence
I am trying to return all customer records who have NOT ordered every year without fail.

Eg,

```
cust1 - 2010
cust1 - 2012
cust1 - 2013
cust1 - 2014
cust2 - 2014
```

As you can see cust1 has not ordered in the year 2011

I would like to return the row that shows cust1.

I need to be able to specify a sequence of dates, eg min and max.

I have tried this:

```
DECLARE @MINDATE AS INT;
SELECT @MINDATE = '2010';

DECLARE @MAXDATE AS INT;
SELECT @MAXDATE = '2014';

SELECT CUSTID, YEAR(DATE) AS [YEAR]
FROM ORDER
WHERE DATE BETWEEN @MINDATE AND @MAXDATE;
```

Comment: PLease delete this question and answers... its a dupe!

Comment: I strongly disagree that this question is a duplicate of the one that was referenced.  I would think that you would have to be pretty proficient in SQL in order to apply those answers to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify sequence like this:

```
DECLARE
    @MINYEAR AS INT = '2010',
    @MAXYEAR AS INT = '2014';

with base as
(
    select @MINYEAR [year]
    union all
    select [year] + 1
    from base
    where [year] < @MAXYEAR
)
select * from [base]
```

Result:

```
year
----
2010
2011
2012
2013
2014
```

Ant then `JOIN` it with your table, for example like this:

```
DECLARE
    @MINYEAR AS INT = '2010',
    @MAXYEAR AS INT = '2014';

with base as
(
    select @MINYEAR [year]
    union all
    select [year] + 1
    from base
    where [year] < @MAXYEAR
)
select y.[year], isnull(b.CUSTID, 'No data') [CUSTID]
from base y
left join ORDER b on YEAR(b.DATE) = y.[year]
```

I don't know how to achieve the desired output because you did not provide any schema of your data

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      #sequence.value
FROM        #sequence
LEFT JOIN   MyTable ON #sequence.value = MyTable.value
WHERE       MyTable.value IS NULL
```

taken from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057491/205426)

Comment: I think it's a bit more complicated than that because the goal is to find all customers who haven't ordered every year. So you would want a temp table of all the years in sequence `CROSS JOIN`ed to a temp(?) table of all customers. Then you could do a `LEFT JOIN` to the actual orders.

Comment: @DavidFaber hmm perhaps, I think I misread the initial question by OP

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to do this with `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT CUSTID
FROM ORDER
WHERE DATE BETWEEN @MINDATE AND @MAXDATE
GROUP BY CUSTID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(DATE)) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(DATE))
                                              FROM ORDER
                                              WHERE DATE BETWEEN @MINDATE AND @MAXDATE
                                             );
```

EDIT:  This assumes that all years are represented in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it reports Customers who do not have orders in all years.

It compares the number of distinct years for a customer against the number of years that there should be based upon the difference between the MaxDate and MinDate.

```
SELECT CUSTID
FROM ORDER
WHERE DATE BETWEEN @MINDATE AND @MAXDATE
GROUP BY CUSTID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(DATE)) <> (YEAR(@MAXDATE) - YEAR(@MINDATE)) + 1
```