# Add a sequence check column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you please help me out with a script to set a new column = whether the column is one more than the column above or not. I want it to check the sequence to detect missing document numbers.

I think I would then obviously need to exclude the first row?

Obviously quite simple in IDEA and Excel just not sure with SQL?

Many thanks,
J

Comment: What version of SQL-server are you using, what does the table look like and what ordering are you using when you say above?

Comment: SQL Server 2008, the table is made up of a column, a list of numerics, 101, 102 , 103. I have a column next to it that I just want to indicate True or False really, where it follows the sequence or not?

Comment: This question seems very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057389/sql-query-to-find-missing-sequence-numbers

Comment: @klas in comments, thanks.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057389/sql-query-to-find-missing-sequence-numbers

Comment: @KlasLindbäck you linked to a sqlserver 2005 question from 2009. Many things have changed since then

Comment: @t-clausen.dk It's the same question. However, since it lacks an accepted answer and others are asking which version I figured there might be better ways to solve it now, hence I didn't mark it as a dupe. If this question gets a good answer (maybe even with different solutions for different versions) we should consider making the other question a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just to check column for gaps then:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( id INT)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES(1),(2),(4),(5),(8),(13),(14)

SELECT * FROM @t t1
LEFT JOIN @t t2 ON t2.id + 1 = t1.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Output:

```
id  id
1   NULL
4   NULL
8   NULL
13  NULL
```

That means that these values break the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The link in the comment from Klas Lindbäck is refering to sqlserver 2005. In sqlserver 2012 you can use [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(LAG_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true)

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 
      coalesce(LAG(a) over (order by a), 0) + 1 = a 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END SequenceIntact, 
    a
  FROM (values(1),(3),(5),(6),(7)) t(a)
)
SELECT 
  SequenceIntact, 
  a
FROM cte
```

Edit: Since you are using sqlserver 2008, you can't use LAG, but you can use row_number - I used dense_rank to compensate for duplicates:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
      a - dense_rank() over (order by a) grp,
      a
  FROM (values(1),(3),(5),(6),(7)) t(a)
)
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN min(a) over (partition by grp) = a 
       and a > 1 -- allowing first value to have SequenceIntact
       THEN 0 ELSE 1 END SequenceIntact,
  a
FROM CTE
```

Result:

```
SequenceIntact a
1              1
0              3
0              5
1              6
1              7
```