# Find missing numbers in sequential int values SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have this table

```
BookNo. | page
001     |  01
001     |  02
001     |  04
002     |  01
002     |  03
003     |  01
003     |  02
```

Is it possible to get the booknos with missing page numbers?

Comment: Can we assume that the highest page number for a book is always in the dataset and the page numbers always start with 1?

Comment: `GROUP BY [BookNo.] HAVING COUNT(*) <> MAX(page)`.

Comment: yes but each book has different number of pages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query to find Missing sequence numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057389/sql-query-to-find-missing-sequence-numbers)

Comment: Thanks I think this will work never thought of that. I'll try it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert. Solved my problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, except where page 1 is missing (written on oracle so syntax may be slightly different):

```
with cte1 as (
select distinct
   BookNo
  ,case when a.page + 1 != lead(page) over (partition by bookno order by page) then page + 1 end as missing_start
  ,case when a.page + 1 != lead(page) over (partition by bookno order by page) then lead(page) over (partition by bookno order by page) - 1 end as missing_end
from test a
where 1=1
)
select *
from cte1
where missing_start is not null
order by 1
;
```

Result:

```
| BOOKNO | MISSING_START | MISSING_END |
|--------|---------------|-------------|
| 001    | 3             | 3           |
| 002    | 2             | 2           |
```