# How I can improve SQL gaps searching code for long tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence, gaps-in-data

How I can improve (speed up) my code for long tables (1M rows)?

I have a table named names. The data in id's column is 1, 2, 5, 7.

```
    ID | NAME
    1  | Homer
    2  | Bart
    5  | March
    7  | Lisa
```

I need to find the missing sequence numbers from the table.
My SQL query found the missing sequence numbers from my table.
It is similar with problem asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057389/sql-query-to-find-missing-sequence-numbers). But my solution is different. I am expecting results like:

```
id
----
  3
  4
  6
(3 rows)
```

so, my code (for postgreSql):

```
SELECT series AS id 
FROM generate_series(1, (SELECT ID FROM names ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1), 1)
series LEFT JOIN names ON series = names.id 
WHERE id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Your query is fine. Hint - `SELECT ID FROM names ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1` is just `SELECT max(ID) FROM names`.

Answer (score 0):

Use max(id) to get the biggest one

[Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/re6zEMGkRwaBSzSsmyQ2BZ/1)

```
SELECT series AS id 
FROM generate_series(1, (select max(id) from names), 1)
series LEFT JOIN names ON series = names.id 
WHERE id IS NULL;
```