# Query to compare two comma separated number string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, compare, string-comparison

I want to write SQL query to compare two comma separated number string and get uncommon result string.

**AttrubuteList1**
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

**AttributeList2**
1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10

Here in above two separate column I want to compare and give result as follows-

**AttributeList3**
4,8

Please help here to get uncommon comma separated string.

Here in above two separate column I want to compare and give result as follows-

**AttributeList3**
4,8

Please help here to get uncommon comma separated string.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057389/sql-query-to-find-missing-sequence-numbers

Comment: Please have a go and let us know where you got stuck.

Comment: The biggest issue here is storing delimited strings like this. It violates 1NF and is nothing short of awful to work with. That being said you should look at [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: @Dale K I agree. I had an answer all prepared and before I could submit they closed the question. Maybe I can submit an edit to the question to get it reopened.

Comment: Because the 2 problems are solved and answered elsewhere, @BartMcEndree . Putting an answer in the comments is the wrong place, like Dale stated. If the OP is truly struggling to make the "jump" of taking the 2 problems and combining the solutions *that* should be their question, and they should be demonstrating what that attempt is and why it isn't working. I'm always happy to reopen such questions when the OP makes a *good* edit.

Comment: I deleted my fiddle link comment. @Monali Bhat If you clarify your question as Thom suggests, we will probably be able to give you a quick answer.